# VirtualBox E_OUTOFMEMORY

Tags: windows-vista, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I've tried running both 4.2.14 and 4.2.16 on Windows Vista Home Premium, SP 2 (64 bit).

Shortly after starting a freshly-installed VirtualBox, I get a

```
Failed to load the global GUI configuration from . The application will now terminate.
```

Details say "Callee RC: E_OUTOFMEMORY (0x8007000E)."

The 4.2.14 was running fine at one one point (with 2GB RAM) but stopped (without a change in memory). It would not come back after several reinstalls and starting from a fresh reboot.

On the Vista machine, it's not even getting to the dashboard. The same VM images come up fine on a Windows 7 (64 bit) machine.

Comment: I bought more memory, but I'm still getting a OOM message with 4 GB.